# Evaluating a Double Integral $\iint \sqrt{x(2a-x)+y(2b-y)}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Please help me in evaluating the double integral

$$\iint \sqrt{x(2a-x)+y(2b-y)}$$

over the region bounded by the circle $x^2+y^2-2ax-2by=0$.

My thought was to change the variable by substituting $x=r(1+cos \theta)$ and $y=r(1+sin \theta)$. so that $0\leq r\leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$. But i could not evaluate the outcome of the substitution. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Given the equation of the circle, you should use the substitution $x = a + r \cos \theta, y = b + r \sin \theta$. Your integral becomes $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} r \sqrt{a^2+b^2-r^2} \ dr \  d\theta$ which is straightforward.

Comment: Than you so much math lover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completing the square we have that the integrand is really

$$\sqrt{2ax-x^2+2by-y^2} = \sqrt{a^2+b^2-(x-a)^2-(y-b)^2}$$

which, when integrated over the circle, $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=a^2+b^2$$ gives half the volume of the sphere $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+z^2=a^2+b^2$$ Thus the answer is

$$I = \frac{2\pi}{3}(a^2+b^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

Comment: Please, if you can elaborate with integration. Thank you.